# Providing optional key without value

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, xkeyval

I would like to prepare a macro with an optional argument like `[wide]`, using `xkeyval`.
(something whether to use `\figure` or `\figure*` inside)
My test program below presents the output

> test0=false test1=false test2=false test3=false test4=false

What do I wrong? It seems to me that the default case stays valid in all use cases.

Also, I an not sure it is the right tool to do what I want. The `xkeyval` documentation states that if no equals sign is present, an error will normally be raised. My test program does not make so. Also, I do not want to use something like `[wide=]`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{METest}{wide}{\def\pb@wide{#1}}
\setkeys{METest}{wide=false}%
\newcommand\METest[2][]{
   \begingroup%
        #2=\pb@wide \ 
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\METest[]{test0}
\METest[wide]{test1}
\METest[wide=]{test2}
\METest[wide=true]{test3}
\METest[wide=false]{test4}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\setkeys{METest}{wide=false}` sets this key to false, so you have no chance to provide another value. `\setkey` should be inside the macro using the syntax `\setkeys{METest}{wide=false,#1}`, such that a possible override within `#1` of the key value is handled.

You can specify a default value to an option, using the `[]` syntax as I have done with the `wide` option key, but not for the `otherwide` key.

If you want to guarantee, that a key has a definite value, `\presetkeys` is the correct command.

### 'Wrong' code, with false usage

This code  will fail on **purpose** to show the missing `=value` for `otherkey` option.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{METest}{wide}[false]{\def\pb@wide{#1}}

\define@key{METest}{otherwide}{\def\pb@otherwide{#1}}


\presetkeys{METest}{wide=false}{}%
\newcommand\METest[2][]{
\setkeys{METest}{wide=false,#1}% 
   \begingroup%
        #2=\pb@wide \ 
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\METest[]{test0}
\METest[wide]{test1}
\METest[wide=]{test2}
\METest[wide=true]{test3}
\METest[wide=false]{test4}
\METest[otherwide]{test5} % will fail here
\end{document}
```

### Correct behaviour

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{METest}{wide}[false]{\def\pb@wide{#1}}

\define@key{METest}{otherwide}{\def\pb@otherwide{#1}}


\presetkeys{METest}{wide=false}{}%
\newcommand\METest[2][]{
\setkeys{METest}{wide=false,#1}%
   \begingroup%
        #2=\pb@wide \ 
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\METest[]{test0}
\METest[wide]{test1}
\METest[wide=]{test2}
\METest[wide=true]{test3}
\METest[wide=false]{test4}
\METest[otherwide=true]{test5} %
\end{document}
```

[image]

### On request of the OP, another solution

This version grabs the `#1` argument of the command first and checks if it is blank. If this is the case, the state is set to false, as requested. Otherwise, the `\setkeys` command is evaluated. However, a wrong usage such as `wide=` without argument is not handled (so far)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{METest}{wide}[true]{\def\pb@wide{#1}}

\define@key{METest}{otherwide}{\def\pb@otherwide{#1}}


\newcommand\METest[2][]{%
  \ifblank{#1}{%
    \setkeys{METest}{wide=false}%
  }{%     
    \setkeys{METest}{#1}%
  }%
  \begingroup%
  #2=\pb@wide%
  \endgroup%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\METest[]{test0}
\METest[wide]{test1}
\METest[wide=]{test2}
\METest[wide=true]{test3}
\METest[wide=false]{test4}
\METest[otherwide=true]{test5} %
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and pointing all this this out. However, what I really wanted, is to provide a 'false' default behavior, and 'true' with [wide] and [wide=true]. The xkeyval doc states that test1 and test3 should provide the same result, 'true'. However,  test0 false, test1 true, test3 true. In other words: if wide is absent, false; if wide is present, then with or without '=true" it should result 'true'. I.e., I want a default behaviour for the macro, and, maybe, a default value for the key. From the docs, I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: I am not sure whether this possible with usage of `xkeyval` alone, but I added another solution

Comment: Finally, after changing to \define@key{METest}{wide}[true]{\def\pb@wide{#1}}, I can get what I wanted. However, when I copy&paste it to my working file, I receive the message "Undefined control sequence \presetkeys". No other errors, the rest is OK. Any idea?

Comment: @user11708: Sorry, but I do not use `\presetkeys` any longer in my updated solution. However, the command must be known of course!

Comment: I am afraid that your other solution is not aware of whether I use another keys.

Comment: OK, I know it must be known, but I receive this error message. I have no idea under which circumstances  it can happen. (so I cannot make easily a MWE, too)

Comment: @user11708: Give an example of another key? Or is it a key from another family?